# Can a typescript function's return type be determined by parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function where one of the args is an array of strings. It returns an object where all of the keys are the values from that array of strings. Is it possible to make the function's return type in Typescript reflect this?

I think this is better explained with an example:

```
const clientConfigs =
    getClientConfigs(clientId, ['timeZone', 'flagRequireTwoApprovals']);

// Above function will return a value for each requested configuration.
// This will look something like:
//   {
//      "timeZone": "America/New_York",
//      "flagRequireTwoApprovals": true
//   }

// At this point, the type of clientConfigs is: Record<string, any>

// HOWEVER, I want the type to be:
//    Record<'timeZone'|'flagRequireTwoApprovals', any>

// I want this to be identified as error, because I
//    forgot to capitalize "Z" in "timeZone":
const clientTime = moment.tz(clientConfigs.timezone).toISOString();

// I want this to be identified as error, because I
//    forgot to retrieve the "adminEmail" config:
await sendEmail({to: configs.adminEmail, body: "Failed to whatever ......"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just make a type parameter for the property names:

```
function test<K extends string>(keys: K[]): Record<K, any> {
  const r: Record<K, any> = Object.create(null);
  keys.forEach(k => r[k] = 'foobar');
  return r;
}
```

Usage:

```
// obj: Record<'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz', any>
const obj = test(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgNKJQD1TABM1EMAnGMAcwD4AKAaxQE80AuRbAbQF0AlFwBKKCHArEcAGkQBDMKzqIA3gChEicWAyIKIsRKnZZCpYgC8iAPIAjAFZioAOggUUc1AzAgANr4EAbg1EFnZnYAkAUTkIAAtmS2UKHiY+S0QAcki4WzkKTKCQ9ygQCiQKYIBfNTUAejrEXPsDcUlMbLg4TMQAHyy8gr6BuQAvTNNFOjVtXWaM1AwGHk7u2UzBiZHxwWCgA)