# Type for a function receiving array of string and returning a record with a key for each string

Tags: typescript

I want to type a function which input is an array of strings. The output is an object with a key for each of the input strings.

This is an example implementation:

```
const getMyObject = (...keys: string[]) => keys.reduce((object, key) => ({
    ...object,
    [key]: `some-computed-value-${key}`,
  }), 
  {},
)
```

So I cant type-safely write something like this:

```
const { keyA, keyB } = getMyObject('keyA', 'keyB');
```

But I don't know how to properly type this function.

Comment: Exact duplicate: [Can a typescript function's return type be determined by parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68566143/can-a-typescript-functions-return-type-be-determined-by-parameters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this:

```
const getMyObject = <K extends string>(
  ...keys: K[]
// Record<K, TypeOfTheComputedValues>
): Record<K, string> => keys.reduce((object, key) => ({
    ...object,
    [key]: `some-computed-value-${key}`,
  }), 
  {},
) as Record<K, string>;
```

This still needs a type assertion because the type of the accumulator in `reduce` isn't `Record<K, string>` until the last iteration, and TypeScript doesn't know that.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygWQJ4HkBGArBxYC8MAPANIwIAeUCYAJhDNAE4CWYcAfABQB0-AawSoIALhikA2gF0AlOIBKeEMzpkANEyhsOnGAT1CRvZgjoBXYAm7cQOPFE1HZ+vdwDeAKBg+Y-Xna4+OrevpJG0uIABhAgALYIALSgcQAO5jR0iQBuAIYANuZJACTuRgC+USE+5bKaoe7lIS65jEqgqhpaOlyenqCQsO4wRgCCTsIAQjDl+vBIaFhBUNwA5GOrmutTq7IA3DAA9IcwAOoqAhD94NAww0YAwhOoACIzc4goGPb4axtbRkmuwOxxgAFFmMwVBBNKkoakEMwoKwEIw6OBVrA4rkoMAABZAA)

Comment: My exact answer, 30 seconds earlier. :-) Nice one!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and contributions!. What if I want to force the output object to have exactly the same keys as the input string?

Comment: @Carlos I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you want something like `{keyA: 'some-computed-value-keyA', keyB: 'some-computed-value-keyB'}`, you could use ``{[T in K]: `some-computed-value-${T}`}``, or do something like [captain-yossarian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68602130/8289918).

Answer (score 1):

You can infer values as well:

```js
type Predicate<T> = T extends string ? Record<T, `some-computed-value-${T}`> : never

type Reducer<
  Arr extends Array<unknown>,
  Result extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown> = {}
  > = Arr extends []
  ? []
  : Arr extends [infer H]
  ? Result & Predicate<H>
  : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? Reducer<[...Tail], Result & Predicate<Head>>
  : Readonly<Result>;

const getMyObject = <K extends string, Keys extends K[]>(...keys: [...Keys]) =>
  keys.reduce((obj, key) => ({
    ...obj,
    [key]: `some-computed-value-${key}`,
  }),
    {} as Reducer<Keys>,
  )

const { keyA, keyB } = getMyObject('keyA', 'keyB'); // keys and values are infered
const { keyC, keyD } = getMyObject('keyA', 'keyB'); // Errors, properties don't match
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIAUBO0AmBLAxgQ1NAPACoB8sAvLAbNAB64B2KAzrI6ImnQOawD8sAStAwB7RCkIAaWAANGwgLbQAtCPmQArrhRKAblgA265QBIA3gQC%200kgC5YdaDuiIQEGANTqMzvMFiwAQUREKlpoBmYgxCxwPHU6AGs6YQB3OiIJPw9GdX1QUPomDxExPCRhGEQIAGlocCl4pNT0slhTCyySciiC8KKAbQBdLL4hrLsemkLmfo4AM2dYAAlh-z5BHLzYADIEZHRsXDwlonHA4N6I2Fm6BZCl6CwUKQA6N-nFgiw0fVXeDxQXh8-TeLy%20P0GUg2uXyuyQqEwOHwDyeRFO-jsgiewjo%20li0LyRAA3CARHRWLBONBQABZcAAeQARgArIT5ch4aqXIqsdhcKS1cDMKZ9ZjVIZEAAUoISdUYdhBb0FjEGAEoyOjYLKhS99kDJZLhCypNr1aQSJLTFl-KCjczMv5-P1tYM7LIFMpVBotLoDEYlGZtVYHbALKqQ-52rAsMxBIDvIhOXKMllVaScRTTFq6gETXUAEKh1pU2kMllsyUAcm1AUrUmrBcrqqJsAA9K3s0LowxYHpDNBmFhkLAPvtgGTM52AMJ58AAESL5BLdKZrIwoCrNbrsAb4HzTZb7dgAFFgqJGFJIIgKs5QGgB7AUDjK-l5DgMAALIA)